# Is this C++ naive primality test done right?

Tags: c++, primes

Here's my C++ code:

```
bool isPrime(double value) {
    if (value == 2)                    // ensure 2 returns true
        return true;
    else if (value <= 1)               // eliminate 1 and all negative numbers
       return false;
    else if (fmod(value, 2) == 0)      // eliminate all even numbers
       return false;

    for (int i = 3; i < sqrt(value); i++) {
        if (fmod(value, i) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

This function should return true if a number given by value is a prime, and false if a number given by value is a composite. First off, I just want to make sure it works correctly, is fairly efficient (it doesn't have to be the best, but I would like it to be decent for a naive approach), and that the code looks nice.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how efficient the implementation is of `fmod()` on your system, but statements like `if ((value & 0x1) == 0)` is likely a faster way to detect even numbers. That's possibly the case with `fmod()` in your for loop as well. You could use `if ((value % i) == 0)` instead.

Answer (score 13):

Is there such a thing as a prime real number?

If not then the function signature should use integer (preferably unsigned as there are no negative primes).

Then you should be able to use `%` rather than `fmod()` which I would suspect is a tad faster but, more importantly, easier to read.

Since you have already checked for all even primes:

```
for (int i = 3; i < sqrt(value); i+=2) {
                            //   ^^^^  No need to increment by 1;
                            //         All evens already checked already so inc by 2
                            //         So just check 3/5/7/9 etc
```

Here is a link to cool but not obvious optimization (That allows you to avoid checking all multiples of `3` as well as `2`): https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/7342/507

Comment: The optimization is interesting (and clever) but seems to  complicate the flow beyond OP goal of a "naive" algorithm.

Comment: @codingoutloud: Your definition of complicated must be different from mine :-) `i+=2`  =>  `i+=t, t=6-t`

Comment: Hi @Loki Astari - IMHO even that simple change would elicit a WTF from many programmers. It is not obvious - not "naive" - what is going on. Your comment did not include all the changes; the loop initialization is also more complex (and, IMHO, also does not pass the initial WTF/naivity test). I am *not* saying that nobody can understand it, or that it isn't a good optimization, etc., simply that it doesn't seem to me consistent with the request for a "naive primality test" as specified in the OP.

Comment: @codingoutloud: OK. I can agree with that :-)

Answer (score 5):

2 things:

1. `isPrime(9)` returns `true` because you're using `<` in the loop's termination clause instead of `<=`.
2. You don't need to add a special case for eliminating even numbers, you can just change the loop's starting point to `2` instead of `3`.

```
for(int i = 2; i <= sqrt(value); i++) {
```

Comment: If I change the loops starting point to 2 instead of 3, and I fail to check for 2, with my current implementation, it says that 2 is composite.

Comment: @Bob: No, I was talking about the even numbers only, not the first `if` statement where you check for `2`.

Comment: @seand - good catch on the isPrime(9)! adjusted my answer to include that.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest the follow edits:

1. Deal only with `int` (or could use `long`, but does not change basic algorithm). This allows use of regular modulo operator (`%`).
2. Could take `sqrt(value)` out of the loop, but not needed for performance since the C++ compiler has plenty of information to optimize it for you.
3. Instead of just a cast for `sqrt`, use `floor` (same effect, but more intent revealing)
4. No explicit test is needed for `2` - it returns `true`.
5. Skip by `2` in loop.
6. Improved comments.
7. Fixed logic flaw with `< sqrt` which should be `<=`

With the resulting code:

```
bool isPrime(int value)
{
   if (value < 2)      // 2 is smallest prime number
      return false;

   // at least one factor guaranteed to appear before sqrt(x) if x is composite
   for (int i = 3; i <= int(floor(sqrt(value))); i += 2) 
   {
      if (value % i == 0)
         return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

This is entirely a style thing, but could also tighten to the following, which looks less cluttered:

```
bool isPrime(int value)
{
   // 2 is smallest prime number
   if (value < 2) return false;

   // at least one factor guaranteed to appear before sqrt(x) if x is composite
   for (int i = 3; i <= int(floor(sqrt(value))); i += 2) 
      if (value % i == 0) return false;

   return true;
}
```

Comment: It's C++ code, not Java.

Comment: Thanks - I updated my syntax and comment - and thanks for the formatting edit to improve visibility of keywords.

Answer (score 3):

If you check for primes a lot, use memoisation to avoid checking values more than once. I would also pre-cache some results and make PrimeCheck class a singleton.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <unordered_map>

typedef std::unordered_map<int, bool> IntBoolMap;

class PrimeCheck {
public:
    PrimeCheck();

    bool isPrimeCached(int value);

    static bool isPrime(int value);

private:
    IntBoolMap checked_;
};

PrimeCheck::PrimeCheck() {
   checked_[1] = false;
   checked_[2] = true;
   checked_[3] = true;
   checked_[4] = false;
   //pre-populate a few results here
}

bool PrimeCheck::isPrimeCached(int value) {
   IntBoolMap::iterator it = checked_.find(value);
   if (it != checked_.end()) {
      //result found
      return it->second;
   }
   bool result = PrimeCheck::isPrime(value);
   checked_[value] = result;
   return result;
}

bool PrimeCheck::isPrime(int value) {
   if (value < 2) return false;

   int max = static_cast<int>(floor(sqrt(value)));
   for (int i = 3; i <= max; i += 2) {
      if (value % i == 0) return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just cache all the primes and the greatest non-prime found?  Assuming that knowing the primeness of `n` tells you the primeness of `n-1` for `n >= 3`, this could save space and you'd still know all primes.  It would lead to lookups being O(lg(n)) instead of O(1), though.

Comment: To generate all the primes up to N, create an array up to N(-1)with factor[x]=x for all values. Then iterate x up to sqrt(N) (x*x < N ) with if( factor[x]==x ) // primes only; for( y = x; (factor[y]==y || factor[y]==x) && x*y < N ){ factor[x*y]=x; }

You end up with a table of the lowest prime factor of every number and a number is prime if its lowest prime factor is itself.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by removing the `sqrt(value)` from the loop condition check. You do not want to compute the square root every time as this will not change for the whole of the computation.
Compute the root once, round it up and cast it to an `int` value.

As pointed by Seand, you need to check the equality to the square root, otherwise you might end up with a false positive with that value.

You do not need to check for multiples of `2` and then start the loop at `3`. Remove the extra check and start the loop at `2`.

Comment: I want to say that modern compilers will cache the result of the `sqrt` call but I'm not sure about that. It's good that you mention it though because caching the value yourself is a good habit to get into for cases where the compiler can't optimize it.

Comment: I don't think you''ll find a compiler these days which can't figure out that optimization. But if you leave it in the loop, you will want to cast it since I believe otherwise the compiler will promote your int value to a double to do the comparison each time through the loop. So `i < int(sqrt(value))` could go in the loop and be better off from optimization point of view. As I did in my answer, I think that `i < int(floor(sqrt(value)))` is more intent revealing.

Answer (score 1):

One inefficiency I will eliminate for you is the test against the sqrt because you are calculating the square root every iteration.

Calculcate it once.

```
for( int i = 3, const iMax = static_cast<int>(sqrt(value)); i<=iMax; i+=2 )
{
   // check
}
```

Of course fmod is potentially less efficient than converting your value to an int once then using % to check for mod.