# Counting the number of primes in C and C++11

Tags: c++, c, c++11, primes, comparative-review

I found this old piece of code that I wrote while I was learning C a while back:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <N>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    size_t limit = strtoul(argv[1], (char **) NULL, 10);
    size_t i, j, res = 0;
    size_t isqrt = (size_t) sqrt(limit);
    char* numbers = calloc(limit, 1);

    for (i = 2; i <= isqrt; i++) {
        if (numbers[i]) continue;
        for (j = i*i; j < limit; j += i) numbers[j] = 1;
    }

    for (i = 2; i < limit; i++) {
        if (!numbers[i]) ++res;
    }
    printf("%lu\n", res);
    free(numbers);
    return 0;
}
```

It's a sieve of Erathosthenes. Since now I started learning C++, I decided to rewrite it in C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <N>" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    size_t limit = std::stoul(argv[1]);
    size_t i, j, res = 0;
    size_t isqrt = size_t (sqrt(limit));
    std::unique_ptr<std::vector<bool> > sieve(new std::vector<bool>(limit));

    for (i = 2; i <= isqrt; ++i) {
        if (sieve->at(i)) continue;
        for (j = i*i; j < limit; j += i) sieve->at(j) = 1;
    }

    for_each(sieve->cbegin() + 2, sieve->cend(), [&res](bool i) { res += !i; });
    std::cout << res << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is this the most idiomatic way to code in C++? I also tried to replace the first for loop with a `for_each` and a functor that accepts `sieve`, but in the end I decided it wasn't worth it and left it like that.

In both versions I am allocating on the heap because the sieve array/vector gets too big for the stack.

Interestingly, the C++ version is faster! I thought they were pretty much identical, but instead the C++ version wins by a large margin:

```
$ gcc --std=c99 -O3 erat.c -lm -o erat
$ time ./erat 1000000000
50847534
./erat 1000000000  11.50s user 0.41s system 99% cpu 11.927 total
$ g++ --std=c++14 -O2 erat.cpp -o erat2
$ time ./erat2 1000000000
50847534
./erat2 1000000000  8.52s user 0.02s system 99% cpu 8.554 total
```

Feedback on the C version is also welcomed!

Comment: Any timing test that shows the 2nd run is faster is suspect given cache loading.  Better to try various sizes and sequences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Idiomatic C++ Review

```
#include <math.h>
```

C++ has its own version of math header.

```
#include <cmath>
```

Difference is all the functions are placed in the `std` namespace.

Prefer not to use `std::endl`.

```
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <N>" << std::endl;
```

Forcing a flush is not normally what you want to do. The streams will automatically flush when required and doing it manually will only make the code less efficient.

Prefer to put one variable per line. Also for loop counters can be declared inside the for statement (see below).

```
    size_t i, j, res = 0;
```

Don't dynamical allocate when a local variable will do:

```
    std::unique_ptr<std::vector<bool> > sieve(new std::vector<bool>(limit));

    // Should be
    std::vector<bool> sieve(limit);
```

Also `std::vector<bool>` is special. It is optimized for space not speed. It also has some other quirks that make it undesirable, so prefer `std::vector<char>` unless you really really need to save space. **BUT** because of the space saving you can get better caching which may improve time. In this case presumably because of the size of the vector keeping it as `bool` makes it much more efficient.

see: [Comparing std::vector to std::vector](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/117880/507)

Declare loop variables inside the `for`:

```
    for (i = 2; i <= isqrt; ++i) {

    // Usually written like this:
    for(int i = 2; i <= isqrt; ++i) {
```

The `at()` method is a checked access to the member. It validates your index is in range (you don't do this in the C code).

```
        if (sieve->at(i)) continue;
```

Unless you are using unvalidated user input there is little need to use the `at()` method, prefer to use `operator[]`.

In C++14 the functions `std::begin()` and `std::end()` were introduced to get the iterators for containers. You should prefer to use these as they work with arrays as well as the standard containers.

```
    for_each(sieve->cbegin() + 2, sieve->cend(), [&res](bool i) { res += !i; });


    // Can be written as:
    auto begin = std::begin(sieve);
    std::advance(begin, 2);
    for_each(begin, std::end(sieve), [&res](bool i) { res += !i; });
```

Don't bother with a return at the end of main.

```
    return 0;
```

Comment: ...except that in this case (like most others) `vector<bool>` saves both space *and* time. See Edward's tests: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/117880/489. It is true that 1) it's not usually the fastest packed storage possible, and 2) it's not a container (as the term is defined in C++), so it should probably have a different name. I doubt that using `vector<char>` instead will provide any meaningful improvement in this case though.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I was just updating the review to that affect. By using char it actually doubles the time.

Comment: Efficiency on a diagnostic error message as in `std::cerr << "Usage: "...` is rarely a concern.  Flushing such output is a good thing.  OTOH, with `cerr` it is redundant.

Comment: `for(int i = 2; i <= isqrt; ++i)` is no good as code, after the loop, uses `i`.

Comment: Disagree with "Don't bother with a return at the end of main."  There is nothing wrong with the explicitness.  At _best _this is a minor style issue.

Comment: @chux: So it both cases my advice stands. 1) Prefer "\n" over std::endl (and use std::cerr for diagnostics). 2) Prefer to declare the loop variable in the for loop (so that you don't leak variable into external scope) unless you need that value in the external scope (in which case you would get a compiler error if you did not).

Comment: @chux: Doing a `return 0` at the end is an indication that there is a possibility that there is a point were I am returning non zero. By not returning anything I am indicating that there is no failure situation. By following this standard pattern you provide more information to the reader. This is also the norm for C++ programs (remember C is a different language with different idioms).

Answer (score 4):

I would say that no, it's not idiomatic C++. There's no reason to use dynamic allocation for your `vector<bool>`, for one obvious example.

As for its being faster, yes, that's expected and fits well with [previous tests](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/117880/489).

If you care about speed, you could at least consider using `operator[]` instead of `at`. I rarely find `at` very useful, personally.

I'd advise against using `std::endl` as a general rules. If you just want a new-line, just write a new-line. If you want a new-line followed by a flush (which is what `endl` actually does) do that explicitly, such as `std::cout << res << "\n" << std::flush;`.

While `res` isn't exactly a *terrible* name, I think something more descriptive (e.g., `result`) would be better. If (for whatever reason) you're concerned about the length of the name, I'd consider using `sum` instead.

Comment: I was allocating on the stack before. But then it blew up when I went past some millions of elements. When I wrote the C++ version I kept it that way assuming that the stack was limited as well. That's why I'm allocating on the heap. Is there another way?

Comment: @rubik: a vector is basically a small object that (internally) contains a pointer to the real data, which is dynamically allocated, so you don't need to do extra work for it to be fine for millions of elements.

Comment: Oh I see. So in C++ dynamic allocation is not necessary, thanks. This makes thinks simpler indeed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Non-portable format specifier with `size_t`.  Use `z`

   ```
   size_t res = 0;
   ...
   // printf("%lu\n", res);
   printf("%zu\n", res);
   // if z not available
   printf("%llu\n", (unsigned long long) res);
   ```
2. `size_t` may be wider than `unsigned long`

   ```
   // size_t limit = strtoul(argv[1], (char **) NULL, 10);
   size_t limit = strtoumax(argv[1], (char **) NULL, 10);
   // or 
   size_t limit = strtoull(argv[1], (char **) NULL, 10);
   ```
3. `size_t isqrt = (size_t) sqrt(limit);` is weak code.  FP `sqrt()` can easily have less precision that `size_t` and `sqrt()` itself need not return integer values exactly as expected.  Better to use an integer `sqrt()`.  Sample follows

   ```
   unsigned isqrt(unsigned num) {
     unsigned res = 0;
     // The second-to-top bit is set: 1 << 30 for 32 bits
     unsigned bit = 1u << (sizeof(num) * CHAR_BIT - 2); 

     // "bit" starts at the highest power of four <= the argument.
     while (bit > num)
       bit >>= 2;

     while (bit > 0) {
       if (num >= res + bit) {
         num -= res + bit;
         res = (res >> 1) + bit;
       } else res >>= 1;
       bit >>= 2;
     }
     return res;
   }
   ```
4. Avoid magic numbers.  Why 1?  Using `sizeof *pointer_type` is correct regardless the type of the pointer `numbers`.

   ```
   // numbers = calloc(limit, 1);
   numbers = calloc(limit, sizeof *numbers);
   ```