# std::vector<bool> workaround in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, vectors, makefile, make

I've been trying to make an `std::vector` of boolean values and I got fed up with the specialization. To get around this, I made a wrapper class around `bool` and a testsuite to make sure that it compiles and works as expected.

It seems to do everything `std::vector<bool>` does, except, of course, `flip()`. It also satisfies the container rules so that you can take a reference or a pointer to an element.

On to the code:

`vector_safe_bool.hpp`:

```
#pragma once

// A wrapper class around bool that can be used in std::vector without breaking container rules

class vector_safe_bool {
    bool value;
public:
    vector_safe_bool() = default;
    vector_safe_bool(bool b) : value{b} {}

    bool *operator&() noexcept { return &value; }
    const bool *operator&() const noexcept { return &value; }

    operator const bool &() const noexcept { return value; }
    operator bool &() noexcept { return value; }
};
```

`vsb_test.cpp`:

```
#include "vector_safe_bool.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#if USE_VECTOR_SAFE_BOOL
using which_bool = vector_safe_bool;
#define TEST_CONTAINER true
#else
using which_bool = bool;
#define TEST_CONTAINER false
#endif

int main()
{
// The commented lines work for neither bool nor vector_safe_bool
    const which_bool t1 = true;
//  bool *t1p = &t1;
    const bool *t1cp = &t1;
//  bool &t1r = t1;
    const bool &t1cr = t1;
//  bool &&t1rr = t1;

    which_bool t2 = true;
    bool *t2p = &t2;
    const bool *t2cp = &t2;
    bool &t2r = t2;
    const bool &t2cr = t2;
//  bool &&t2rr = t2;
    t2++;
    ++t2;

    std::vector<which_bool> bv(10, true);
#if TEST_CONTAINER
    for(auto &b : bv)
        ;
#endif
    for(const auto &b : bv)
        ;
    for(auto &&b : bv)
        ;
    const std::vector<which_bool> cbv(10, true);
#if TEST_CONTAINER
    for(auto &cb : cbv)
        ;
#endif
    for(const auto &cb : cbv)
        ;
    for(auto &&cb : cbv)
        ;
}
```

`GNUmakefile`:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-deprecated -pedantic -std=c++11

all:

check test: vsb_test.cpp vector_safe_bool.hpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -I. vsb_test.cpp -DUSE_VECTOR_SAFE_BOOL
    @rm -f a.out
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -I. vsb_test.cpp
    @rm -f a.out
```

What I'm looking for:

- Can I make this more idiomatic? How?
- Can I make use of features from newer versions of C++?
- Did I forget any obscure corner-cases?
- Is there anything that I can make better in the GNUmakefile?
- Are there any other ways that I could improve this?

Comment: We can make the wrapper as close to `bool` as possible, but there is some limitations (e.g., `decltype`, template parameter deduction, etc.).  In the end, there is no way to make `bool` itself usable with `std::vector`, so unfortunately sometimes libraries have to reinvent `std::vector` :(

Comment: @L.F. It works for my purposes, but do you see anything that could make it closer to `bool`?

Comment: If you're doing this for performance reasons, I'd strongly suggest testing.  See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117880/comparing-stdvectorbool-to-stdvectorchar for possible inspiration.

Comment: I find it funny that this question gets attention almost two years later when I wouldn't write anything akin to this now

Comment: Just use [Boost's `vector`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/container.html).  It intentionally does not have the `bool` specialization.  The common work-around is to use `std::deque` instead.

Answer (score 4):

If you aren’t reinventing the wheel as a learning exercise, and want to code this productively, the simplest options are to use the Boost version of [`Boost::Container::Vector<bool>`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost/container/vector.html), which does not specialize to a bitfield, or something like `std::vector<unsigned char>` or perhaps `std::vector<std::byte>`, letting a type the same size as `bool` decay to `bool`.  Other suggestions [in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670308/alternative-to-vectorbool) have included using `std::deque` or specializing the allocator.

If you’re going to re-implement this `vector_safe_bool` type encapsulating `bool`, you probably want to define `operator(bool)` and `vector_safe_bool& operator= (bool)`, which would let you assign `bool` values to and from the vector.  You might also need to define bitwise operators for expressions such as `v1[i] &= !v2[i]` to work.

Additionally, there’s no point in passing or returning a type that fits into a register by `const` reference.  It’s more efficient to pass by value.  And you should allow this type to be `constexpr`, so you can use use it in the initializer-list of a `constexpr std::vector<vector_safe_bool>` in C++20.

Comment: std::vector is actually `constexpr` in C++20.

Comment: @user673679 So it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Makefile review:

All makefiles should have `.DELETE_ON_ERROR:` to ensure erroneous output doesn't satisfy dependencies.

The targets `all`, `check` and `test` should be declared as dependencies of `.PHONY`.

It's unusual to have a Makefile for a header-only library, but I think we can still make use of default rules for the two tests:

```
clean:
    $(RM) vsb_test

check test:
    $(MAKE) -B CXXFLAGS+=-UUSE_VECTOR_SAFE_BOOL vsb_test clean
    $(MAKE) -B CXXFLAGS+=-DUSE_VECTOR_SAFE_BOOL vsb_test clean
```

Probably also a good idea to have the compiler auto-generate header dependencies:

```
CXXFLAGS += -MMD
-include vsb_test.d
```