# A C++ program to check if a string is a pangram

Tags: c++, strings

I'm new to C++ and decided to implement a simple program that checks if a string is a pangram (i.e. the string contains all the English alphabet letters). It's my first program in C++ and I have some background with interpreted programming languages like Python and R.

I want to know what are the common beginners mistakes I'm making in this implementation, whether I'm following good practices, what I should avoid etc.

### The Code

````
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool isPangram(std::string str) {
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::toupper); // Transforming a string to upper case
    std::vector<bool> hash_table(26, false); // a hash_table that maps the  index of a letter from the alphabet
                                             // and a boolean saying if the string contains this element                                             
    int index;
    for(auto c: str){
        if(isalpha(c))
            // Checks if the element in the string is in the alphabet
            index = c - 'A';
            hash_table[index] = true; 
            std::cout << index << std::endl;

    };

    if(std::any_of(hash_table.begin(), hash_table.end(), [](bool v) { return !v; })) {
        // if any of the items in the array evaluates to false
        // means that the string don't contain all the elements 
        // in the alphabet,hence, it's not a pangram

        return false;
    }
    return true;    
};

int main() {
    std::string str = "We promptly judged antique ivory buckles for the next prize"; 
    if (isPangram(str)){ 
         std::cout << "Yes" << std::endl; 
     }
     else {
         std::cout << "No" << std::endl; 
     };
     return 0;
}
```
````

Comment: For a beginner, it's amazing I'm not seeing the most-most common mistakes of: No STL; C as C++; `using namespace std;`; You even have an appropriate use of `std::vector<bool>`!

Comment: @Casey, thank you! I went after some C++ good practices before implementing this code, but, i knew that i wouldn't get everything right.

Comment: @Casey: Arguably, for a table that's known to only need 26 elements, it would be worth the 26 bytes for a `vector<char>` instead of 26/8 bytes to hold 0 / 1 values for a present/absent status.  So although `vector<bool>` is the obvious choice for a container here, the requirement that it be specialized as a bit-vector (https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool) is actually *not* ideal for this use-case.   Also given the small fixed size, `std::array<bool, 26>` would be good here.  (For a beginner's first C++ program, though, this is more than fine, and not "wrong" per-se.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah, hence "Appropriate", I personally would have used a `std::bitset` as it is a known length and fixed length. I would go as far to say a `uint32` and bit-twiddling would have been a considerable alternative. But only in rare cases where performance was warranted.

Comment: @Casey: yeah, bitset is decent, although for long strings, [setting a bit could be more expensive than a cached store to an array index](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/257256/#comment508170_257262).  (Depending on how smart your compiler is, e.g. using x86 `bts dst, src` to implement `dst |= 1<<src` or doing it manually.)  Unfortunately standard library `isalpha ` and `toupper` aren't fast enough for the data dependency to probably matter, but the overall throughput cost can matter.  And for short strings being very fast to clear initially and check at the end is great. :P

Comment: @Casey: Out of curiosity, GCC -O3 codegen for AArch64 is pretty nice https://godbolt.org/z/1v9KP1 (after fixing the `if(){}` braces and moving toupper into the loop after isalpha), but neither toupper nor isalpha inline. (For ASCII it's super cheap to turn a char into a 0..25 index into the alphabet, or detect that it's non-alphabetic, with OR + SUB and a compare/branch. [What is the idea behind ^= 32, that converts lowercase letters to upper and vice versa?](//stackoverflow.com/a/54585515), but ASCII isn't the only 8-bit charset, although non-UTF8 8-bit charsets are less and less relevant)

Comment: The `isalpha()` may check the local which opens it up to a lot of other characters not in the English language. Thus you may get letters that our outside `'A' -> 'Z'`

Comment: @Casey `using namespace std` just turns C++ into a more human language in which you can just use the darn words without `simon says std::`.   The usability advantage of `using namespace std` outweighs the theoretical problems, like your program clashing with future versions of the library that introduce more identifiers. Worrying about the distant future is a fool's errand; you can whack name clash moles on the head as they pop up.

Comment: Actually some compilers do through an error if the main function has a return type but no return statement.

Comment: @Kaz> I have seen so many real bugs in real applications coming from this "theoritical" problem, that I just see your comment as misguided (and no, name clashes do not always pop up, they can also change the behavior of your program without even generating a warning). If you want the convenience, you can name types explicitly with `using std::string;`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here are a number of things that may help you improve your program.

### Make sure you have all required `#include`s

The code uses `toupper` but doesn't `#include <cctype>`.

### Eliminate spurious semicolons

The code has a number of spurious semicolons immediately after closing braces.  They don't bother the compiler but they will bother any other programmer who looks at your code.

### Check your `if` statements for proper braces

It appears from the indentation in the `if` statement in the `isPangram` routine is not what you intended to write.  The only thing that is currently associated with the `if` statement is `index = c - 'A';` -- all of the lines after that are executed in every case.

### Initialize variables before use

The `index` variable, as mentioned above, may or may not actually get initialized to anything as it's currently written.  That leads to *undefined behavior* of your program, which is not a good thing.  Best practice is to initialize variables when they are declared.

### Return `boolean` values directly

The `isPangram` ends with this strange construct:

```
if(std::any_of(hash_table.begin(), hash_table.end(), [](bool v) { return !v; })) {
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Here's a much more direct way to do that:

```
return std::all_of(hash_table.begin(), hash_table.end(), [](bool v){return v;});
```

Similarly, within `main`, I'd write this:

```
std::cout << (isPangram(str) ? "Yes" : "No" ) << '\n';
```

### Consider a more efficient approach

Consider that the the `transform` must necessarily visit every letter.  We then make another pass through with the main loop.  It is possible to do everything in a single pass.

### Don't use std::endl unless you really need to flush the stream

The difference between `std::endl` and `'\n'` is that `std::endl` actually flushes the stream. This can be a costly operation in terms of processing time, so it's best to get in the habit of only using it when flushing the stream is actually required. It's not for this code.

### Eliminate `return 0` at the end of main

When a C++ program reaches the end of `main` the compiler will automatically generate code to return 0, so it is not necessary to explicitly write that.  Some people prefer to do so for style reasons, but it's important to know that it's not required by the standard.

### Consider using <s>`std::span`</s>`std::accumulate`

If your compiler is C++20 capable, this would be a good use of `std::accumulate` (not `std::span` as I originally wrote).  This version is faster than [anything so far](https://quick-bench.com/q/-B7bLMm24sikZyGigsmdW8Qdsik).

```
// helper function for isPangram_accum
constexpr uint_fast32_t charToMask(const unsigned char c){ 
    // can't use non-const toupper in constexpr function
    unsigned index{(c | 0x20u) - 'a'};
    return index < 26 ? ~(1u << index) : ~0;
}

bool isPangram_accum(const std::string& str) {
    uint_fast32_t present{(1u << 26) - 1};
    constexpr auto letterMask = [](uint_fast32_t collection, char ch) {
      if (collection)
        collection &= charToMask(ch);
      return collection;
    };
    return std::accumulate(str.begin(), str.end(), present, letterMask) == 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::isalpha` also requires `<cctype>`.

Comment: Perhaps `std::string_view` would be more appropriate than `std::span`?

Comment: Just for S&Gs I implemented your more efficient suggestion: The `std::string` declaration, the `std::vector<bool>` declaration, an optional-for-readability lambda declaration, a call to `std::transform`, a call to `std::all_of`. Done.

Comment: Hey @Edward! Thank you for your contribuition i'll have a look at span and those annoying semicolons and all the other things you've pointed out!

Comment: Wouldn't you want `charToMask` to return `~0` aka `-1` for the non-letter case, to leave all the bits set when you `&` together all the masks?  I would have maybe used `|` to combine `1UL << index`, especially since you called it "present", although your way does have the advantage of making an early-out on `present == 0` even more efficient on many CPUs.  Note that `1U` isn't guaranteed to be a 32-bit type, so `1U << 16` or more could overflow on implementations with 16-bit int.

Comment: I would have used `uint32_t` because many compilers / C libraries, including unfortunately x86-64 glibc, [unwisely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36961100/how-should-the-uint-fastn-t-types-be-defined-for-x86-64-with-or-without-the-x) make `uint_fast32_t` a 64-bit type, which as I mentioned in my answer will make auto-vectorization worse.  Speaking of which, out-of-range chars could be mapped to a different bit-position (like 0 or 26) instead of to not changing the bitmap. 
 That could let smart compilers use a saturating subtract instead of a compare/AND.

Comment: @PeterCordes: good point on returning `~0`.  That was a bug I've now fixed.  Thanks also for your other useful points and comments.

Comment: You're still missing portability to implementations where int is 16-bit.  Use `~(1UL << index : ~0UL` to fix that, and in the initializer.  (Or like in my answer, explicit casts to the exact type you want, like `uint32_t(1) << index`

Comment: Would using a simple table-lookup not work better? Just change that one function: `constexpr auto charToMask(unsigned char c) noexcept { constexpr auto table= []{ std::array<unsigned char, 1u + (unsigned char)-1> r; for (unsigned i = 0; i < r.size(); ++i) r[i] = std::min<unsigned>((c | 0x20) - 'a', 26); return r; }(); return 1 << table[c]; }`

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd point can be combined together: Use a linter or formatter to ensure consistent coding style / convention.

Comment: @Deduplicator: not really; and the bit-shift can actually auto-vectorize (see my answer) but a LUT would defeat that. If compilers do a good job, `1UL<<index` is pretty cheap, even with clamping.  Also, you'd need to keep that LUT somewhere, or initialize it every time you use it.  Maybe it could give a minor speedup for long strings, if the pure bit-manipulation is a bit slower, but it would make startup overhead worse.

Comment: @PeterCordes You know the LUT is a compile-time constant? And stashing 256 byte somewhere should not be such a burden. Whether one lookup (byte for a byte) versus bitwise-or + subtract + clamp is a bargain, or auto-vectorizing steals the show, I don't know.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Yeah, but the first access might miss in cache.  Or actually, GCC decides to write `table` to the stack before using it, since it's in automatic storage.  Even at -O2 or -O3 https://godbolt.org/z/qWh6zz (init from mov-immediate or copy from .rodata respectively).  But C++ doesn't let us make it `static` in that scope.  (We could make it file-scope.)  Also, if you're optimizing for x86, might want to have the table hold `unsigned` `1<<idx` constants to allow memory-source OR, instead of load + BTS.  (Or worse, legacy `shl reg,cl` 3 uops on Intel, then an OR. GCC10 does use BTS.)

Comment: (Only some of the elements will be "hot", but yeah with that many elements probably uint8_t shift counts would be better than uint32_t masks.  I was forgetting the point of the LUT was to avoid range-checking.  Still questionable whether it's worth doing; only for really large strings, and when you can't get the pangram check to vectorize.)

Answer (score 10):

- The sequence

  ```
    if (condition) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  ```

  is a long way to say

  ```
    return !condition;
  ```
- `std::all_of` seems more natural than `std::any_of`, which implies double negation.
- `std::toupper` is declared in `<cctype>`. Make sure to explicitly `#include` it.
- In programming, `hash_table` has very special meaning. I strongly recommend to rename it to `present` or something like that.

Comment: Thank you, @vnp, I've thought about  using `std::all_of` but for me it seemed that `std::any_of`` was the more efficient way, i did not knew that any_of implied a double negation.

Comment: Strictly speaking this *is* a hash table, with the identity function as a hash and a hard-coded load factor of 1. But it's still not a good name since it doesn't convey useful information.

Answer (score 8):

There's a problem hidden here:

> ```
> std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::toupper);
> ```

The problem is quite subtle (more subtle the missing include of `<cctype>` or misspelling of `std::toupper`).  It's that `std::toupper()` accepts a positive `int`, and plain `char` may be signed or unsigned.

Promoting signed `char` to `int` may result in a negative value, but we need a positive value, usually achieved by converting to `unsigned char` and allowing that to promote to a (positive) int.

For a safe version, we have to write

```
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(),
               [](unsigned char c) { return std::toupper(c); });
```

Similarly, we need to replace

> ```
> for(auto c: str){
>     if(isalpha(c))
> ```

with

```
for (unsigned char c: str) {
    if (std::isalpha(c))
```

---

Another portability bug lurks here:

> ```
>     if(isalpha(c))
>         // Checks if the element in the string is in the alphabet
>         index = c - 'A';
> ```

There's no guarantee that the host character set contains all upper-case letters in any particular sequence.  Of particular note, on EBCDIC systems, `'Z'-'A'` is significantly more than 25 (it's 37 if I remember correctly), and we'll write outside the bounds of `hash_table`.

For portable code, we need to change how we store the values - perhaps use a bitset of length `UCHAR_MAX`, or perhaps a `std::set`.  Then test whether there are any `std::isalpha()` characters not present.

Comment: Thank you ! That is  a really subtle problem, i need to study more on the data structures/tpyes that c++ provides. as close friend said to me: "C++ gives you enough rope to hang yourself" you need to know how to use the language correctly

Comment: I was curious what exactly would happen with negative args to `std::toupper`. According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper, *If the value of ch is not representable as `unsigned char` and does not equal EOF, the behavior is undefined.*.  So a value sign-extended to a negative `int` would indeed cause UB.  A plausible implementation of toupper (on a system with 8-bit char) could be using the `int` to index a 257-char lookup table, with the `[-1]` index having something for EOF=-1.  More-negative indices could even go off into an unmapped earlier page.

Answer (score 4):

Note that your entire strategy of assuming 26 alphabetic upper-case characters, and that they're between 'A' and 'Z', breaks if there are any high-8-bit accented characters in a non-UTF-8 8-bit character set.  So the locale-aware `toupper` and `isalpha` are just slower for probably no benefit.

Several comments have discussed using a "better" data structure for your set of seen letters, because [`std::vector<bool>` is unfortunately required](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) to be specialized as a bit-vector.  (Good data structure for some things, especially *large* bitsets, bad choice of name to expose it in ISO C++, as [Howard Hinnant argues](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool)).  For this use-case of only 26 elements, it's slower than necessary.

The two good choices here for efficiency (and clean concise code) are:

- [`std::bitset<26>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) - very cheap to init and check (and convenient with `bitset.all()`), relatively cheap to update on most ISAs.  (Better than `std::vector<bool>` because the template can specialize itself for the known size being <= one unsigned long or whatever chunk size the library uses.  So the compiler will have an easier time being sure it can just keep one integer in a register and OR bits into it.)

  std::bitset is so cheap to check, literally just an integer compare for a small bitset (smaller than the bitness of the machine you're compiling for, which is usually at least 32 these days), you could even consider an early-out check every iteration if you expect very long strings where all 26 letters appear far before the end of the string.  (Maybe unroll by 4 so you check every 4 chars).

  With an ASCII-only replacement for isalpha and toupper, some compilers (e.g. clang and ICC) can even auto-vectorize the bit shift / OR, effectively checking 2 to 4 characters in parallel for only somewhat more than the cost of one.  (Or even 8 characters in parallel if you replace std::bitset with `uint32_t` to avoid the silly compiler widening to 64-bit integer elements.  Or even 16 with AVX-512)
- [`std::array<bool,26>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) - Unlike `vector<char>`, no dynamic allocation required (it doesn't indirect to separately allocated storage: the object *is* the array, which is totally fine for a small fixed size like 26).   Less cheap than bitset to init and check (especially if the compiler doesn't do a smart job), but even cheaper to update for each char of the string, especially on CPUs like modern x86 where a byte store is extremely cheap, [not even an internal word-RMW when committing to L1d cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217528/are-there-any-modern-cpus-where-a-cached-byte-store-is-actually-slower-than-a-wo), although non-x86 CPUs will often do more store coalescing in their store buffer making byte stores still fairly cheap, and likely not a bottleneck unless you *seriously* optimize the isalpha and toupper checks. (It will hit in cache every time because the array is tiny).

  In theory a smart compiler could check for all 26 byte elements of being set fairly efficiently, with two partially-overlapping SIMD 16-byte loads and a SIMD AND (then on x86 for example, pcmpeqb against 0 / pmovmskb to check for any elements that matched a zero).  But in practice GCC is dumb and fully unrolls 1 byte at a time compare/branching.

### The clean portable way, not optimizing for ASCII-only

Still only using narrow `char`, though, not `wchar_t` and not using UTF-8 aware stuff.  non-UTF8 charsets other than ASCII are increasingly rare these days.

Probably a good idea to just use `toupper(c) - 'A'` and manually check if that's unsigned `<= 25`, instead of using isalpha: on a POSIX system for example, if LOCALE or LC_ALL aren't `"C"` (the POSIX locale, pure ASCII), `isalpha` can also return true for allow accented characters whose upper-case codepoint is also outside the 'A'..'Z' range.  For example in a locale like ISO-8859-1 or probably also Windows-1252, somewhere from 0x80 to 0xff.

```
bool isPangram(const std::string &str)        // note: const-ref arg
{
    static_assert('Z'-'A' == 25, "we assume a charset where letters are contiguous");
    std::bitset<26> present(false);
    //std::array<bool, 26> present = {0};

    for(unsigned char c: str){          // note: unsigned char instead of auto to work around legacy C unsigned-char value range in int arg requirements
        if(isalpha(c)) {      // FIXME: isalpha can return true for high-8-bit c
            auto index = toupper(c) - 'A';
            present[index] = true; 
            // std::cout << index << '\n';
        }
    }

    return present.all();   // nice semantic meaning of "all present"
    //return std::all_of(present.begin(), present.end(), [](bool v){return v;});
};
```

(Compiles and runs, with complete `#include<>` list and an improved main, [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tQVvQAZPLUwA5YwCNMxEAFYAnKQAOqBYXW0eoYmgj5%2BanRWNvZGTi4eisqYqgEMBMzEBEHGppyJKhG0aRkEUXaOziAAzAAciumZ2SF5Cg2l1uWxlbUAlIqoBsTIHADkUlXWyIZY4lU66q3EmMxGs9jiAAwAguOT05izOovWwGubWwD0F7u0UwYzcwBuyUTEZ9s3d1gA1IcOhEoCO8dpIJrd9r85hliMwAJ7Az4Qw5sYAkQgIVZVdYfUF7e6YSE6AxqViEeFY86I/GE5CqWFeA4Uj7bByofTfPAKAAKImAMKMEDQtFa31a6BAIGOol%2BkgAbIsepSAOyybbfdWi9JqZAAfWYCiUmQgYBGAC0TQBaE1bE2QgAiszt30krlIMskAHcCfqFMZvd9kAgMoDvh6EM4CewCARnApvhkCUK1MADAMFFJJIqqqqthrNeKQP8CIDDnK1t8vEslPRqGwlFmc3mrmKJdC4X82aw3WWsRWq1oCPbfiqNuIlQ7s5S1RqaMQIAZhXhgDZ0AGg8QAyBNcRFSq8xqrt9aKgY1uF35l5hV4GMhzhTHmKvUFR48TUN8iKGSABrePEAbaN87DAMwyCwt8OjfOeS4rhaN4bo8bAGASMKiAS1h3oOGTAN8SwAI4GHgSxGAO6bTvuHJUBAnJsF4QaCj0PTDo2FH7swb53lgAAeQ5EAYXgMnOyBMRa3zWiaszSAeFzfPOi6XugPR8QJzgMd8ol%2BAAXpgOoEMaIw2iMTEcnGCiksACAEKw4FGCQBKYFQVB4MgeADt8s5/jC4HWNxJzfHQ3xcTUspug4xIBqgRheHg7Bxh6JBKO5JDfEWIYeui3wAOI6Do5ysfulaYNWQKuNIPmYFx4iuE6jofsQyGSb85H5d8h4tigAyDochycRVhI9RJrg6LQEmTs1eZjg6zWTVOuYaksBCDLQfZFQOAB0bCsBADbSUezkEkoRgiNq3wkSIfnPu6m0rcVGZ5dJC1LfmrasKwOrPhAhXFWtTjANY21ul963mADvylVVdoQKy7KPLu0iPcQy2PJJk0NsqE45uch4I8KHLoFxbqIaS6BreqeAvkTeDoG6VM8Zyd5g9IGxrWtLoQ%2Bc1ikjY6rtV4zBEYc0EKWuGSkNDrDlvqLl4DqUYxsQtNyReK6YQGiofCq93qm1BAK6o1nfFsDA6AAkibboAFTHgQFv%2BQQ4YbjUFpFiLxCAgoa1a61Mn2wSaJ/bQbDfPg6AjSMg7xcQv4eQAqgAKgAYhaNSnQYrBqM7sIxvGtIDlerugfLcYiLCHpwqF4XHrQFrxwnKdOy78Hu5qMWsN8FWckCzVCyr8FASwiW1RISo6BsXGSKOY1zeqPf533tFBjqtNDqwA8EqJJrMKNUnazJzOs64SUbgvzBONqpPfAA6q3oYwl4R8F6osYpcoqAemJIxbyMbrJafqDPM6Q%2BHlywmk0hJZqONmInyXvjN08ZWB0WYDAni3UqhOlnugfSYCRhWk/iaXcGN0azUPOxIgFpniqDRNpOKGUpi8gvlsQC6V7aGwAGoAA1JBujrO%2BbKkERCrhNjlT22xDzfDjuGSi21vjPDdgEYOqAioyOcOBWg%2B0DbMIQGw9hFpXCcC4SlcKaAooxWfugd8kdEqaPVOLfqcwjznFsZyHkoh%2BR6gUNLHUxjorsGIFQBW5hrKCjoCKdqUocJSHlLrdWOxNbNWbAQAsqVMBAjmD2bAN0By1lYPWFG3drAECqJIXSKVCBHXvrVSeO9vbxkeKgKm3xZTcGdoQUU746HSlIagchLwqFKM0Z1UMVMtB%2BT5iKIpLSCAiJ2M1WcSsYJz3XJubccMvZ5i6XjFBaD4weLwDLOWzhFbCTydPfcVxyayVpmtJQQpFK7Q6ThGSQj%2BFvh6cgduzxlrWN9pRNZGoxwsRat7IG9AqplXxmtJybsSo1W2brBqU8gW71FAgcmg4ZIAHkABK/kXzMG%2BBsHZ8YjzdNQPfDyVcLQnzPs5EyL9ozOA/EGZaXhiRqE6RBAAshi1h/llo/OQArbUQc%2Bb2z%2BRRMRAj26BwcLFLKOUPzvi6W814eBtLcMHOwfUEcMpbA4ZIB%2BiEFan3YBaBQqKqBd1OflIs5Thy5W2YRegRTdLUQhTcugdzUGQSuVC1ojUamcBjhYOxkEvxp1XE4RpzSXZSqOt%2Bb0ryKGqs0swQoX43aYGmflGa01xyzTzO1ZJqSdDpMyfQIctrmBeBOXmSBIKpmbW2gGw8VaKloNqhAINIbvXOllCJb4nATkzSnrNApp1%2Ba0GkQCr2YTdZ%2BUWEODMl8CSVkil4Ky4E%2BD3GAPnY6eACLoTqcQcCYVkDfjlR5H5NguKDkrGqg4khJABpqfCg4zV2poHCr26i3JeT8ggAqSECd3RvqqsNDM3wtwZioHWA4Q1aAZh2mcmS1sOBHkwB6Lm6FwT4lXBhcJZFTmLtqki90K6%2Bzrs3d8bd6Bd2rn3Yewx57L3JWvRVO9CttJ3WzC1Q8sGcnvuI4kiUX6upzB6r%2BlxfIViAeicB0D9V4MQafVB90AmlDgcQ0%2BtGECUlPSqUQ5kIIJgviwE5FcEAdQ6iCrKazTExy5RHsHByHRMHWdszqJp9msY%2B1RXGemYY03ysghbc1AxWDoFtlG8xflrHtTbLCGm95lhPhfPbYLCt8DIDTmmdyadrIWgXP%2BV6%2BcHBZ29FhD8eASIBiihcPgtJKS4lwz8Q4NWjAFIVrQNaCBgS2MDMkb8Opjw6m0v%2BBQwT7zPRAIljs%2BhuyynLJE6EDm4mnOs0YfRNQ8AyM4EOHURgjCy1QI%2BAwOo/DbagEKEUm3tt4Atg5uUq2X0ofckREUnBZQpQq0RvMd3JA7ZkQa2qh3jusFO%2Bgc7l3AfXZCYOAHO3HsyllNCMFcoLRfYhjtQ8whPvfc%2BiUPAQd/7OGEF4GJeZHj7dB0dvU2gLt4Cu9TwmmZa0ampwdunyAoqYDwjqTA0UagQBZ98MHF2UnjdQIzq7jEX2HkpVLyi8ZaCnoqxOggg2GPfCl17SBYAwDi9ss8I6ChhuC7wML6nunYlTRM%2BYcmRkhAgBGK4b%2BpgRgbG/qgF3uUZByDaYMYYMoqicG/gQF3XvGKkHDI%2BSoANvxuFlGtVwrhZR6KVJwJUNQNhKlcBsDYrpWAu%2B4N/IwXAC%2BkA9170gPuRjfwUCADYpAI%2Be6d3AWAMBEAdRMb48glBvGmJcA8zgnANh5CcunWMlAHCR%2B/v8QOJ6Xdh9IMYki9AMW0GsnP0gWAjqiHYDv/ASwUjPEb230gFVkjElGDXgpygd%2BkgcDCE9egsDL/DwrcvIww99BoPQJgNgDgHgfgEALhYQUQFAOQOQIQPABwRvSAPoMlQoc/C0DFKodSMUR0CQf3GQLPdSI6IYPrNBIMBQL0V6Agg0TAbgdSKgY8IrWgErVgC0CHMlBQBvJIFIDQCAcwJoXIS/bQMoGIOIUIXwfwOgPg0Q8IAIIQioFwFoTgwoYoRofQHIQQJQAoVINoWQroeQ%2BoEoSQlobQjoYQyoTgPoBQAYIYYAvoYvV3d3HfOvWzC0JpAMCAnCUfNaZmfbCAXAQgZKcYPICCddIfEPTMCCaAmQcPOfaPWPLAFwBPEAbgKoNabgZI7gGoQHSQTgdwF0Z3EYUvUgcvJUJUNaHI7gPPSQEo7gdwJUCopUKvRwl3BvJvFvGI0gDvbvTqVlAgfvYJXvSoLhK8fwvQ//RgFgQ/EAj0O%2BD/Wwl3N3Roi/OvcYA1axZw1wh5QdTgLwso6ItvWI1LePOYgosvMAyQNaHPVwSQCop9fPF0J9EKavb3ZoxQVo1vKPPoRPZI1I9IzIzInIvIuwqoBwpYl494oyY4yQEEmvOvPYj40gWRPwDQbgIAA%3D%3D%3D).  Along with some experiments for pure-ASCII, and a manually-vectorized function with SSE2 intrinsics to check a `std::array<bool,26>` for being all non-zero.  Clang's bitmap update is clever for x86-64: With EAX holding the `toupper` return value: `dec al` / `bts  r15, rax`.  `'A'` is ASCII 65, and the [`bts` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bts) (bit test-and-set, like `dst |= 1<<src`) with a reg destination masks the bit-index by `&63`, like `%64`, so `c-'A'` is equivalent to `c-1` as a shift count in x86 asm.  I don't know why clang thinks using a partial register, AL, is a good idea.  Other compilers do worse.)

This also shows other improvements mentioned in other answers:

- `const std::string &` by-reference arg, which we *don't* modify.  Instead we do `toupper` inside the loop, and only for alphabetic characters.  If you're used to Python, "applying" something to a whole list can be faster than looping manually, but that's because of Python interpreter overhead, where you want to get into a compiled C loop in the Python interpreter.  C++ always compiles to native machine code, so you can mostly loop as fast as any `std::` template function can.  (In theory template functions could use tricks like manual SIMD vectorization, but in practice that's unlikely.  However, C library functions like `memcmp` or `strchr` *are* often hand-written in asm, so that's one case where you have fast building blocks that you can't replicate with portable C++, only with intrinsics like x86 `_mm_cmpeq_epi8` to do 16 byte-compares in parallel.)
- `unsigned char` because `toupper` and `isalpha` expect their arg in an `int` (because those functions date back to early C before function prototypes even existed).  But they expect the character code to have the value-range of `unsigned char`.  Perhaps a good way to remember this is to imagine that they're implemented by using the `int` arg as an index into a table of character attributes for the current locale (which is actually true on many libc implementations), so a negative `int` from sign-extending a signed `char` would be a problem.  That won't happen if your characters are purely ASCII; those are always positive-valued `char`s, but in general don't assume that.  On many ABIs (including the mainstream x86 ones), `char` is signed.  (Fun fact: ARM C/C++ implementations use unsigned `char`, so your code wouldn't have this problem there.)
- `{}` after the inner `if()` so the if also controls *using* the index.  I also moved the declaration of `index` into that scope because there's no need for it outside.
- static_assert to check that 'Z'-'A' == 25.  Non-ASCII / non-UTF-8 character sets are possible in portable C++, but actually making your code slower because of the possibility isn't something you always want to do.  But if possible, you can avoid silent failure there.

### ASCII-only

Neither of `isalpha` and `toupper` will inline, with gcc / glibc / libstdc++.  That's normal; non-ASCII locales may have accented characters.  But just for fun since we're not handling modern UTF-8 anyway, lets see how fast we can go for ASCII.  And because the whole strategy of 26 slots revolves around plain ASCII, not accented upper-case characters.

It only takes a couple operations to check it for being alphabetic, by turning it into an index into the alphabet and checking if that's in the 0..25 range ([see this SO answer: set the lower-case bit, then one sub / unsigned compare as a range check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54536362/what-is-the-idea-behind-32-that-converts-lowercase-letters-to-upper-and-vice/54585515#54585515)).  In our case, we actually want that index, so this is perfect.  Turns out the check can even auto-vectorize decently, especially with AVX2, allowing compilers to check multiple characters at once.  (You can still see asm for the scalar version in a clean-up loop after the vectorized version.)

(Instead of benchmarking, I actually just wanted to look at the asm; turns out clang has some neat tricks up its sleeve and without AVX2 for variable-shift with a per-element shift count, it adds a value into the exponent of a float `1.0` and does float->int conversion to get a per-element `1<<idx`, I think.  Other compilers just give up and use scalar.  Clang also seems to be doing an integer multiply as part of the vectorization, and I don't know what that's about.  Haven't fully reverse engineered how it vectorized, and IDK whether it's a real speedup :P)

```
// I also tried  unsigned int  for most of these; compilers widen sooner for that
// clang isn't usefully getting more work done before widening, but GCC might be

// returns idx, valid.  if valid, idx is in [0..25]
inline  std::pair<unsigned char,bool> ascii_letteridx(unsigned int c)
{
    // strictly ASCII, *not* other 8-bit charsets.
    // the original didn't work for UTF-8 multi-byte accented characters anyway, but non-UTF8 8-bit charsets still exist
    unsigned char lcase = c|0x20;
    unsigned char alpha_idx = lcase - 'a';   // 0..25 for alphabetic.  Will wrap for characters below 'a', or above 25 for > 'z'
    return {alpha_idx,  alpha_idx <= unsigned('z'-'a')};
}


// auto-vectorizes with clang.  And with AVX2, also GCC and ICC.
//  The if() version does very nicely with AVX-512, but compilers do worse with  bool << n
bool isPangram_ascii_compilerfriendly(const std::string &str)
{
    //std::bitset<26> present(false);
    uint32_t bitmap = 0;   // avoid 64-bit so clang auto-vectorizes without widening past 32-bit.

    for(unsigned char c: str){
        auto idx = ascii_letteridx(c);
        //if (idx.second)   // clang / ICC auto-vec even with the if
        {
            //present[idx.first] = true;
            // shift / OR of a 0 as a no-op for non-alphabetic is better than putting a CMOV on the critical path
            //  and enables GCC to auto-vectorize, at least with AVX2 for variable-shift
            bitmap |= uint32_t(idx.second) << idx.first;  // 1UL <<  would be 64-bit and make auto-vectorization worse.
        }
    }

    std::bitset<26> present = bitmap;
    return present.all();  // bitmap == (1UL << 26) - 1;
};
```

These comments are *not* a recommendation for how to write code, just leftover notes after looking at how it compiles with gcc, clang, and ICC, for various x86 targets (e.g. `-march=sandybridge`, `-march=haswell` (includes AVX2), `-march=skylake-avx512`)

Comment: A [quick benchmark](https://quick-bench.com/q/hepHGb8DTsomvxWrEvuDLayGC-4) shows that compared to the original, the `bitset` version is 18 million times faster and the `vector<bool>` equivalent is 1400 times faster.

Comment: @Edward: That smells fishy, like constant-propagation after inlining for the compile-time constant string.  But on your link, I'm seeing `BM_isPangram3` (bitset) as 1.9x faster than `BM_isPangram2` (`vector<bool>` with toupper inside the loop, manual isalpha.  Oh, good point, `isalpha` would return true for high-8-bit accented chars in 8-bit charsets!  So this whole strategy is only safe for ASCII anyway.)  And 570x faster than `BM_isPangram1` (`vector<bool>` with fully original method).  I'd believe 2x for startup / check overhead, and 570x is somewhat plausible, oh you left in printing!

Comment: Yes, I left in printing from the original.  If we remove it (making all routines more similar) we the `bitset` version is 17,000 times faster and the `vector<bool>` version is 1.4 times faster.  Note, too, that I have used a longer test string that actually contains two pangrams.

Comment: @Edward: oh, and according to the QuickBench assembly output after I removed printing from pangram1 (https://quick-bench.com/q/umLvnM-7VzOkmjJA7CMLEmAFBBw),  BM_isPangram3 spent all its time in an empty loop, adding `-1` (0xfff...fff) to RBX).  You need some Benchmark::DoNotOptimize in there to consume the result and defeat CSE across iterations, because `isPangram3` can inline into it.  (The other 2 didn't inline and so actually got called, so another option would just be to put `__attribute__((noinline, noclone))` on pangram3.

Comment: @Edward: here's a valid version, where the bitset work isn't optimized away or hoisted out of the loop `bitset` 2.3x faster than #2 `vector<bool>`: https://quick-bench.com/q/3qu88BxW3Un0YU7_wTO7TN6gjIk  I had to use `benchmark::DoNotOptimize(result);` in the BM_ loop to make sure it actually called it every time.  (I also made the functions `noinline`, which is kind of the opposite of what we want for the perf record output from the asm dump: better to have them inline into the loop.)  I guess there's no way to pass `-march=native` or whatever on QuickBench :/

Comment: Also interesting is that LLVM's `libc++` also gives a performance boost over GNU's `libstdc++`.

Comment: @Edward: Oh yeah, I had meant to try libc++, it's often more compiler-friendly (or at least clang-friendly).  I see it's a lot faster for bitset (like 172ms vs. 645ms or whatever units), and also about twice as fast for vector<bool>.  So the relative advantage of bitset increases, as well as being a lot faster in an absolute sense.

Comment: Instead of returning a char/bool pair, wouldn't returning `min(tolower(x)-'a',26)` be faster?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Yeah that's another possibility, doing a `cmp` / `cmov` on the index-into-alphabet.  That would let compilers use `bts` to implement `bitmap |= uint32_t(1) << idx;`, instead of manual shift and OR.  Or with SIMD, unsigned min is a single instruction in SSE4.1 / AVX: [`pminud`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pminud:pminuq).

Answer (score 3):

This is good use of the standard library, and the code is quite good for a beginner.

The main thing that sticks out to me (aside from the points mentioned in the other answers) is that you are passing the input string to your function by value, which creates an unnecessary copy of the string for a function that should just need to read the string and return a boolean. Normally, such a function would accept its argument as a `const` reference, but the call to `std::transform` prevents this (at least, the `const` part of it). The call to `std::transform` isn't really needed anyway (and results in another, unnecessary loop through each letter), since you can call `toupper` in your `for` loop.

I would also suggest using a `std::unordered_set<std::string::value_type>` instead of a `std::vector<bool>`. This will allow you to call `std::unordered_set::insert()` in your `for` loop, which only adds the letter if it isn't already in the `std::unordered_set`. Then, instead of calling `std::any_of` at the end (a loop through possibly all 26 elements of the `std::vector<bool>`) you can call the constant-time `std::unordered_set::size()` to determine if the set contains all 26 letters.

Here's how it would look:

```
bool isPangram(const std::string& str) {
    std::unordered_set<std::string::value_type> hash_table;

    for (auto c : str) {
        if (isalpha(c)) {
            hash_table.insert(::toupper(c));
        };
    };

    return hash_table.size() == 26;
};
```

Finally, if you do use your original code it would be best to use the proper type for `index`: not `int`, but the `size_type` of the container your are indexing (i.e. `std::vector<bool>::size_type` for your original container).

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` often trips people up because despite its name, **`std::vector<bool>` is not a standard container**, having a subtly different interface, and performance issues, too.  Although counter-intuitive, `std::vector<char>` is almost always a better choice for storing booleans.

Comment: Using a `std::unordered_set` here is very inefficient. The `vector<bool>` is better, but best would be a `std::bitset<26>`, and then you can call [`std::bitset::all()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/all_any_none) to check if all letters of the alphabet are present.

Comment: Hey @Null, thanks for your contribuition. I've seen some people using pointers to iterate through things in C++, that's really new to me and i've seem some posts in SO about using pointers just when you really need them. Do you think it would be more useful passing a string pointer sas argument to the `isPangram` function?

Comment: @TobySpeight `std::vector<bool>` is often faster in my testing. See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/117880/39848

Comment: @Edward: Yup, `vector<bool>` has is place, and that place is for large data sets, like a prime sieve or something.  For *this* case, `std::bitset<32>` could be good to enable quick checking (setting is only quick on systems that have something like x86's `bts reg, reg` to implement `reg |= 1<<reg` efficiently), or `std::array<char, 26>` (where memory indexing makes setting cheap, without any data dependency between elements.  i.e. setting an `A` doesn't have to wait for a store to `arr['B'-'A']` to complete.)

Comment: On some non-x86 microarchitectures, even `std:array<int,26>` could be better, more likely to allow higher throughput commit to L1d cache from the store buffer without needing an internal RMW cycle in the L1d cache to modify a byte in a word if the store buffer couldn't merge multiple writes to the same word into one commit.  [Are there any modern CPUs where a cached byte store is actually slower than a word store?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54217528)

Comment: Modern x86 CPUs have byte granularity for cache writes so `char` would definitely be best, to make checking all 26 bytes cheaper.  (One or two SIMD loads to get all the data back. Probably pad to `array<char,32>` so the compiler can check all 32 bytes for non-zero with one AVX1 `vptest ymm` (maybe after setting `array[26..31]` to one?  hmm, non-trivial to handle the padding), or SSE2 maybe two overlapping 16-byte loads that span the whole 26 bytes, ANDing them together, then check that they're all non-zero.  Anyway, storing a `1` is cheap, esp on ISAs with indexed addressing modes.

Comment: "instead of calling `std::any_of` at the end (a loop through possibly all 26 elements of the `std::vector<bool>`) you can call the constant-time"… technically O(26)=O(1) 

Comment: Edward and @TobySpeight: forgot to link Howard Hinnant's comments on when a bit-vector is useful  - https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool.  He agrees that `vector<bool>` was a poor choice of name for it, but it has its uses, and a standard library with good specializations for it can go fast checking or counting many bits at once for stuff like `std::find`.

Comment: @Occhima A `const` reference for the argument makes a little more sense than a pointer in this case, but a pointer would be better than passing by value since it also would avoid the unnecessary string copy. For discussions about pointers vs. references see [Pointer vs. Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/114180/3964927) and [When to use references vs. pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7058339/3964927).

Answer (score 0):

Another comment says "Initialize variables before use".
I would turn that around and say something like:

**Avoid declaring a variable without initialization**

The problem occurs in:

```
int index; // Could change to index=0;
for(auto c: str){
    if(isalpha(c))
        // Checks if the element in the string is in the alphabet
        index = c - 'A';
        hash_table[index] = true; 
        std::cout << index << std::endl;

};
```

But the solution isn't to initialize index with 0 (or -1), but to move the declaration until you can initialize it as follows:

```
for(auto c: str){
    if(isalpha(c))
        // Checks if the element in the string is in the alphabet
        const int index = c - 'A';
        hash_table[index] = true; 
        std::cout << index << std::endl;

};
```

The reason for moving the declaration is that `index` will have a smaller scope so it is easier to keep track of (for programmers) - and by making it `const` you don't have to check if it is changed anywhere.